# how to specify the version of a plugin dependency when using Maven BOM files

Tags: maven

I have a Maven BOM file which I import into my project pom:

```
     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>be.company.mvn</groupId>
                <artifactId>be.company.mvn.bom.core</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

works fine for dependencies, and even for plugins. But now I also want to control the version of the dependency of a plugin used in project pom:

```
   <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
         <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>

         <dependencies>
           <dependency>
             <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
             <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
           </dependency>
       </plugin>
```

Is it possible to get this working? I want to specify the version of commons-dbcp in my BOM file without having to specify it as a dependency of the jetty plugin in the BOM file too.

Comment: An import will not work for plugins, cause the import scope will only use the dependencyManagement part...

Comment: thats strange because I tested it and the pluginManagement part seemed to get imported

Answer (score 7):

There is an opened issue for that [MNG-5588](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5588?jql=project%20%3D%20MNG%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC) (opened in Feb 2014...). Feel free to vote for it.
At the moment, only a "classic" parent pluginsManagement can be used.